# Problems with getting listview cache using volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

For some reason i am unable to retrieve the cache response using volley.

This is my fragment :

```
RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).getRequestQueue();

        JsonObjectRequest JOR = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if(getActivity()!=null && isVisible()){
                        try 
                            {
                            JSONArray posts = (JSONArray) response.getJSONArray("posts");

                            for(int i=0; i<posts.length();i++){
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                //TAG_TITLE.add(posts.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                                String title = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_TITLE);
                                Log.d("Checking Title", "title"+TAG_TITLE);
                                String message = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                                String myevent_img = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_IMG);
                                String sponser = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_SPONSER);
                                String whoinvited = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_WHOINVITED);
                                String location = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                                String dresscode = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_DRESSCODE);
                                String time = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_TIME);
                                String endtime = posts.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_ENDTIME);

                                //_list.add(myevent_img);
                                 map.put(TAG_SPONSER, sponser);
                                 map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                                 map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                                 map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                                 map.put(TAG_ENDTIME, endtime);
                                 map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                                 map.put(TAG_WHOINVITED, whoinvited);
                                 map.put(TAG_DRESSCODE, dresscode);
                                 map.put(TAG_IMG, myevent_img);
                                Log.d("jobj ", "event_img"+myevent_img);
                                Log.d("hashmap ", "sponser "+map.get("sponser").toString());
                                eventList.add(map);
                            }
                            } 
                        catch (JSONException e) 
                            {
                            }

                            Log.d("getActivity ", "getActivity is not null");
                        adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), eventList);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else
                        {
                            Log.d("getActivity ", "getActivity IS NULLL!!");

                            //list.setAdapter(null);
                            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                    }}, new Response.ErrorListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError Error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });

        //queue.add(JOR);
        JOR.setShouldCache(true);
        Entry entry = queue.getCache().get(url);
        if(entry!=null){
            Log.d("Cached", "CACHE Is Present!!");
             try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8"); Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            queue.add(JOR);
            }
```

I am using a VolleySingleton which deals with the caching.
Entry ALWAYS seems to be null. Am i missing any code.
Really all i want is to get the listview to retrieve data from the cache when no network connection is present.

Answer (score 0):

The volley architecture takes care of this for you. If the response for a given URL is already cached by the Volley L2 disk cache, requesting the URL from the `RequestQueue` will return the response immediately without going out to the network. Conceptually, you're not supposed to manually retrieve Volley's cache and look through it because that's exactly what Volley does before returning your response.

**Please Note:** in order for what I just described about caching to work there are 2 prerequisites:

1. You have to have successfully made the request when you did have a network connection. This is kind of obvious - the data has to come from somewhere.
2. Volley's default disk cache caches every response (unless instructed otherwise) according to *HTTP cache headers*. If there are no cache headers / the cache headers have expired, the response will **not** be available in the disk cache.

**Side note:** Images loaded via Volley have the benefit of a memory cache as well.

**Possible solutions (ordered according to best first):**

As a preliminary step: remove the code that manually goes through Volley's cache.

1. No further action needed, since the JSON response you are receiving has the appropriate cache headers.
2. The JSON response doesn't have any cache headers, but you control the server - add the appropriate cache headers to the response.
3. Manually override the default caching strategy in the Volley source files to better accommodate your needs, e.g. always cache everything / cache specific URLs / etc.
4. Maintaing a separate disk / memory cache and manage your own caching of JSON responses. This could lead to duplicate caching (both you and Volley cache the same JSON in 2 different places) and thus up to twice the amount of disk space your app takes in the device's memory.

Comment: Oh cool, i will Try this. Thank you for the response, i had already given up and used an Sqlite database instead.